# Distribution of pre-transformed Gaussian Random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be monotonic and differentiable functions, and suppose that $(X, Y)$ is a random vector such that

$$
(f(X),g(Y))^T \sim N (\mu, \Sigma),
$$
where $\mu = (\mu_1, \mu_2)^T$ and $\Sigma$ is a 2x2 covariance matrix. We therefore have that

$$
g(Y)|f(X) \sim N(\mu_2 + \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2} (f(X) - \mu_1), \sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2}).
$$

I'm interested in the distribution of $Y|X$ though. Is there a closed form expression?

Comment: Are the functions *strictly* monotonic (or, even better, diffeomorphisms)? Otherwise, the chances of a closed form expression are pretty low imho.

Comment: If they were diffeomorphisms, is the result straight forward?

Comment: If $X$ is a diffeomorphism, then knowing $X$ and $f(X)$ is equivalent, so conditioning on both gives the same formula. To go from the probability of $g(Y)$ (conditioned on $X$) to the one of $Y$ (conditioned on $X$), use the "change of variables formula for probability densities" applied to $g$ (or $g^{-1}$). Does this help?

Comment: Sorry,  I meant probability *density* of....

Comment: $$p_Y(y|X=x) = p_{g(Y)}(g(y)|f(x)) \cdot \left|\frac{dg^{-1}(v)}{dv}\right|_{v=g(y)}$$
$$p_Y(y|X=x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (\sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}^2}{\sigma_1^2})}} \exp\left(-\frac{(g(y)-\mu_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2} (f(x) - \mu_1))^2}{2(\sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}^2}{\sigma_1^2})}\right) \cdot \left|\frac{dg^{-1}(v)}{dv}\right|_{v=g(y)}$$

Comment: @rumathe this should be the answer instead of a comment (with the assumptions on $f$ and $g$ being diffeomorphisms).

Comment: @IljaKlebanov I would appreciate if you make an answer using my considerations

Comment: @rumathe Done. I had to modify (basically, invert) the last factor, though. I added a reference. Can you please verify? It is just so easy to mess up where to put $g$ and where $g^{-1}$ etc. 8[

Comment: @IljaKlebanov yes, very accurate, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned and worked out by rumathe in the comments (I had to make a small correction of the last factor), an explicit formula for the probability density of $Y|X$ can be computed using the change of variables formula (for probability densities) under the *additional assumption that $f$ and $g$ are diffeomorphisms*:

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then knowing $X$ and $f(X)$ is equivalent, so
$$
g(Y)|X \sim N\bigg(\mu_2 + \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2} (f(X) - \mu_1), \sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2}\bigg).
$$
To go from the probability density of $g(Y)$ (conditioned on $X$) to the one of $Y$ (conditioned on $X$), one can use the [change of variables formula for probability densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) applied to $g^{-1}$:

If $Y = h(Z)$ and $h$ is a diffeomorphism, then
$$
p_Y(y) = p_Z(h^{-1}(y)) \, \bigg| \frac{\mathrm d h^{-1}}{\mathrm dy} (y)\bigg|.
$$
Hence, in your case with $Z = g(Y)$ (conditioned on $X$) and $h = g^{-1}$,
$$
p_Y(y|X=x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (\sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}^2}{\sigma_1^2})}} \, \exp\left(-\frac{(g(y)-\mu_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}}{\sigma_1^2} (f(x) - \mu_1))^2}{2(\sigma^2_2 - \frac{\sigma_{21}^2}{\sigma_1^2})}\right) \cdot \bigg| \frac{\mathrm d g}{\mathrm dy} (y)\bigg|.
$$